# Count substrings with atmost k 1's and 0's

Tags: string, algorithm

Given a binary string of 0's and 1's how to find the number of substrings from index l to r where l and r are given in queries (Q) such that from l to r it has atmost k 1's and 0's .I have a O(n^2) solution but here the queries are about 10^5 so how to solve this problem.
Ex: given string 01110000 and k = 2 so for l=2,r=4 answer is 5 and l=5,r=8 answer is 7.

Comment: @downvoters. I know this question does not fit SO guidelines, but when you downvote, leave a comment to justify it

Comment: From amalsom: @arunmoezhi: http://www.codechef.com/MARCH15/problems/STRSUB -----This is probably the reason for downvoting.

Answer (score 0):

Very brief sketch of an offline `O(n + q)`-time solution.

Index the queries by start and stop. For each position `l` in increasing order, we can determine the greatest `r` such that `l..r` is a valid substring. `r` is nondecreasing in `l`, so this takes time `O(n)`. Keep a cumulative count of the valid substrings. Extend this loop so that, whenever we move `r` onto the right endpoint of a query, we add the cumulative count to its answer (initially zero), and when we move `l` onto the left endpoint of a query, we subtract the cumulative count from its answer. There is some special case logic for queries that are themselves valid substrings that I'll leave as an exercise.

Comment: How is it n+q ? Shouldn't it be n*q ?
For every query , you are checking valid string for every position i where l<=i<=r and adding count of substring at that position which is O(n).

Comment: @Manish I meant what I said, but since this is an active contest problem, I'm not going to explain it any more.

Comment: Hehe ! I know what you meant. Been there Done that. It is just that unless and until you mention both forward and backward pre-computation , it will be n*q only.